Number of adults per country
I would like to find the number of adults per country. It's easy to find total population, but the proportion of adults will clearly vary a lot.

The definition of "adult" also varies per country. Do you want to take that into account? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_majority

@NicolasRaoul Ideally, I would have one definition. I don't care too much whether it is e.g. 18, 21, or something else. I can see population pyramids for many countries, but doing the calculations by hand would be cumbersome.

I don't know if 25 is an acceptable definition of adult to you, but with the data from the UN, you can find the population aged >25 by country: https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/population-by-age-group-with-projections There's an icon at the bottom of the interactive chart, to download a static version of the graph but also the raw dataset by country in csv format. Once you downloaded the csv file, if you filter by year and add the age groups "25-64" and "65+", you can find how many people over 25 there are in each country. It seems surprisingly difficult to find more detailed info than that.

Thanks @J-J-J . I was also surprised that the data is not easy to get. I can combine the estimates for age 25 and 15 and get a good approximation.
